# What's up with this weird Wells Fargo account nickname policy?

Tags: savings, banking, bank-account

This question is super random, but I have a savings account that I want to throw 10% of my money in per month for savings. I wanted to nickname it "Tithing", and Wells Fargo gave me this error:

[image]

What's up with that?

Comment: This really isn't a personal finance question, and even if it was it seems extremely localized.

Comment: Sounds like a *clbuttic* problem to me.

Comment: To clarify, "clbuttic" is a programmer's joke. Poorly-designed "bad word" algorithms may remove or change the bad words even if they are in the middle of another word. The classic example is "classic" being changed to "clbuttic". Hence, mbhunter is suggesting that the bank may be objecting to the "tit" in "tithing".

Comment: mine won't let me call it 'carpe that dime' cause of the word dime... but nickel works...and so does penny... why is this happening to me!?

Comment: @mbhunter: No, this is a Scunthorpe problem, not a clbuttic problem.  They're blocking, not changing.

Comment: @LorenPechtel good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't mean to be flippant, but why not try "titster" or similar and see if the first three characters are the issue. If it's accepted, than you should ask the bank why they are discriminating against your religious beliefs. If it's rejected, then you know they are going overboard on avoiding certain words.

Comment: I think it's very likely that this is the reason.

Comment: Separation of church and bank?

Comment: Well, the banks essentially own the govt, thus separation of church and state/bank.

Comment: The use of the word Tithe is permitting government promotion of a specific religion?

Answer (score 2):

Certain phrases are blacklisted, I am not 100% about tithing but it might be they don't want any flak about people claiming that Wells Fargo is the one tithing (with a religious connotation)

Either that or a super conservative ban on "tit", but I would guess the former more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Um  really, you expect US to know the answer?  Why not ask Wells Fargo?

Unless someone here happens to work for WF and has access to the right people, this is more likely a question to send to their support people than to get an answer here that is anything other than a SWAG   (and in that line of reasoning, and as a software tester by trade, my money is on the already offered reasoning that it's doing some kind of primative 'bad word' search (probably a regular expression match) and getting a hit on tit.  )

In the meantime I suggest an alternative term, how about 'offering'